# tableView - didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableView` which is embedded in a `UIView`, acting as a dropdown view (see image). However, it is not responding to cell user touches (testing using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function). Please see below code.

How this works is that the dropdown view is that it is a subview of a button (which is in a static `UITableViewCell`), so that when the button is touched, the dropdown view height changes from `0` to `88` (and the cell height changes too).

I checked the view hierarchy and nothing is blocking the view from registering the touch.

**Dropdown view custom class**

```
class GenderDropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var genders = ["male.", "female."]
var tableView = UITableView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.addSubview(tableView)

    // Table View constraints
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    // Table view design
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.allowsSelection = true
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = genders[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .medium)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(genders[indexPath.row])
}
}
```

**Configuring dropdown view in parent `UITableViewController`**

```
func genderDropdownViewConfig() {
    genderDropdownView.backgroundColor = Constants.azureColor
    genderDropdownView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    genderDropdownView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    genderDropdownButton.addSubview(genderDropdownView)

    genderDropdownButton.addSubview(genderDropdownView)
    tableView.bringSubview(toFront: genderDropdownView)

    genderDropdownView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderDropdownButton.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    genderDropdownView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderDropdownButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    genderDropdownView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderDropdownButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    //genderDropdownHeight = genderDropdownView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    genderDropdownHeight = genderDropdownView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)

    for subview in genderDropdownView.subviews {
        subview.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let heights = [280, 130, 103, 103, 103, 103]
    if indexPath.row ==  2 && genderIsOpen == true {
        return 191
    } else {
        return CGFloat(heights[indexPath.row])
    }
}

@objc func genderDropDownTouched() {
    if genderIsOpen == false {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.genderDropdownHeight])
        genderDropdownHeight.constant = 88
        genderIsOpen = true
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.genderDropdownHeight])

        // Editing height of cell
        tableView.reloadData()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.genderDropdownView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.genderDropdownView.center.y += self.genderDropdownView.frame.height / 2
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.genderDropdownHeight])
        genderDropdownHeight.constant = 0
        genderIsOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.genderDropdownHeight])

        // Editing height of cell
        tableView.reloadData()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.genderDropdownView.center.y -= self.genderDropdownView.frame.height / 2
            self.genderDropdownView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually, failure to respond to touch is because the view is _outside its superview_. Check to see whether that's the case.

Comment: @matt - thanks for responding. I believe it is in my superview, just added another image which I believe proves this

Comment: An easy way to check is to add this line in GenderDropDownView: `self.clipsToBounds = true`. If that causes the table view to become invisible, it is outside the drop down view.

Comment: @matt Thanks for sharing this trick. I just added the line, and the table view does not become invisible, so it must be in the superview

Comment: FYI - `layoutSubviews` is not the proper place to set the table view's data source and delegate nor the place to add the table view as a subview. `layoutSubviews` can be called many times. The only code that should be in `layoutSubviews` is code that updates the layout of subviews. All of the code you have in `layoutSubviews` should be in `init`.

Comment: Okay but you need to try that for the whole chain of superviews. This is very worrying: "How this works is that the dropdown view is that it is a subview of a button". Okay, but if the dropdown view is outside the button, it will be untouchable. Try the same thing on the button.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for this note

Answer (score 0):

> How this works is that the dropdown view is that it is a subview of a button

But the dropdown view appears outside the button. Therefore it is outside the bounds of its superview, and that means it cannot respond to touch.

Comment: Just enabled the button to have `clipsToBounds = true` and it was indeed invisible. What should I add the dropdown view to be a subview of?

Comment: To the superview of the button? I really can't tell you that; I'm not designing this app. I feel I've answered the question. The mystery was why the table view was not touchable, and the mystery is solved.